# Error in Auth Google Video API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use this Google API:

> 

I downloaded the Sample Project and followed the steps that are:

1) CD Project Folder API Video

2) npm install

3) set GCLOUD_PROJECT = neorisvideo

4) I downloaded Json from the Credential and inserted it inside the Project folder

5) I ran the command node analyze.js labels-file resources / cat.mp4

And gave the following error:

> ERROR: Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.
>       at C:\Users\thiago.saad\Downloads\nodejs-docs-samples-master\nodejs-docs-samples-master\video\node_modules\google-auth-library\lib\auth\googleauth.js:316:21
>       at C:\Users\thiago.saad\Downloads\nodejs-docs-samples-master\nodejs-docs-samples-master\video\node_modules\google-auth-library\lib\auth\googleauth.js:346:7
>       at Request._callback (C:\Users\thiago.saad\Downloads\nodejs-docs-samples-master\nodejs-docs-samples-master\video\node_modules\google-auth-library\lib\transporters.js:70:30)
>       at self.callback (C:\Users\thiago.saad\Downloads\nodejs-docs-samples-master\nodejs-docs-samples-master\video\node_modules\request\request.js:188:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\thiago.saad\Downloads\nodejs-docs-samples-master\nodejs-docs-samples-master\video\node_modules\request\request.js:884:8)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9) (node:9196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): Error: Could not load the default credentials.
>   Browse to
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information. (node:9196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Could not load
>   the default credentials. Browse to
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information. (node:9196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Error: Could not load
>   the default credentials. Browse to
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information. (node:9196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): Error: Could not load
>   the default credentials. Browse to
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an environment variable to point to the json file:

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/user/project/google.json`